# Alfresco Authentication Subsystem Devloppement

Tags: authentication, alfresco, alfresco-share, subsystem

I need to install an alfresco using a custom authentication service based on xml messages.

I think the best way for this is to use a custom subsystem. But I don't find anny docs on how to dev an alfresco subsystem.

Did someone have something that can help me ?

Comment: Did you try looking at the [Alfresco SubSystems wiki page](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Alfresco_Subsystems)? Subsystems are basically just a self-contained set of Alfresco beans, with spring config to only expose certain bits, so largely are the same as developing any other Java stuff for Alfresco

Comment: I read this page, but i prefers concerts examples. And docs for alfresco dev are a bit hard to find.

Comment: Alfresco is Open Source, so your best examples are what Alfresco itself does! Config wise, [start around here](https://svn.alfresco.com/repos/alfresco-open-mirror/alfresco/HEAD/root/projects/repository/config/alfresco/subsystems/) and authentication wise, [start here for code](https://svn.alfresco.com/repos/alfresco-open-mirror/alfresco/HEAD/root/projects/repository/source/java/org/alfresco/repo/security/authentication/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alfresco uses the Spring Security Framework. You might be better off developing a custom authenticator that plugs in to that framework versus writing an entirely new sub-system.

Comment: Is this possible without any modifications of alfresco sources?

Comment: It should be because you would wire in your code through Spring without touching Alfresco's, but I haven't done it in a long time so I can't say for sure. Worth exploring for sure.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will certainly ask other questions on the implementation later.